# Magento 1.9 Impossible Login?

Tags: magento, authentication, click, admin, panel

I've searched everywhere for an answer and I can't seem to find a solution to the problem I'm facing, hopefully this will help others in the future as well.

I am unable to login to my magento admin panel. I'm able to input my username and password per usual, but my login button doesn't "click". My mouse recognizes the button as a button and changes to the "finger" cursor, but when I click nothing happens, no button animation to show click confirmation, no URL changes, no refresh as if there was an "invisible layer" in front of it preventing the click. The results are consistent through multiple devices and browsers. I've cleared Cache and session data.

Anybody have any clue what could be going on or know of a potential fix? Much Appreciated~

Comment: Can you try press enter instead of clicking to see if anything happens ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Open your browser's developer console and check if there's anything weird going on with the submit form. It is a pretty straight forward standard form submit together with the varienForm js functionality. Also have you tried pressing enter after typing your login data instead of clicking the button? That should also submit the login form. Make sure to disable all browser extensions that could interfere such as noscript or adblockers.